# Running Multiple Firefox Windows from one Profile in Private mode (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file, firefox

I tried to run multiple windows in private mode on firefox with the same profile, however the windows dont open with the specified profile, or they open inside the same window...

This is my code:

```
@echo off


start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P lifestyle -new-instance -private-window 
ping 127.0.0.1 > nul
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P lifestyle -new-instance -private-window 
ping 127.0.0.1 > nul
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P lifestyle -new-instance -private-window
```

I added the ping127... for waiting 1 second before opening a new window.

How can i achieve this now since this doesnt work?
p.s. Putting the new-instance before -P or lifestyle doesnt work either...

Answer (score 0):

I think `-new-instance` only works on unix, try `-no-remote` instead.

Comment: With -no-remote it asks me to close the other tab.

Comment: you cannot use the same profile for multiple instances, whether it be by `no-remote` or `new-instance`, both options are intended to allow multiple firefox instances on different profiles to be open simultanously.

Comment: So there is no direct way? Even not by opening a new private window inside the first window

Comment: if you want to open a private window for an already-open session just add `-private-window` and nothing else